# Update Ruby Gemspec Metadata After Publishing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

Is it possible to change the source code link of the gem, after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only by publishing a new version of the gem.

You **could** yank (delete) the old version, but I would strongly advise against it. Yanking should only be done for "extreme" errors such as critical security or legal problems.